# Better run sequentially or in parallel several IO (disk) intensive applications

Tags: performance, io, parallel-processing, disk

In case there are several IO (disk) intensive applications, which one would perform better, running them sequentially (one at a time) or in parallel?

Comment: This is highly dependent on what your storage configuration looks like. For a single-spindle spinning-rust disk with a file system on it, it would probably make the most sense to run things sequentially. For a RAID set that has multiple spinning disks, some parallelism should be ok. For a wide RAID set consisting of NVME static memory cards, much higher parallelism can be expected...

Comment: It also depends on the IO pattern of the applications.  For example, if all the applications do small-sized random IO operations, it won't really hurt the *total* time to run all the applications no matter if you run them sequentially or in parallel - and it's even quite possible the entire set could run *faster* when run in parallel if any of the apps aren't IO-bound as other apps do IO while the non-IO bound apps do computations, for example.  If the apps do large sequential streaming IO operations, running them in parallel will probably hurt performance.